# How to mock IMessageReceiver

Tags: azure, moq, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

The Test

```
// arrange
_messageReceiverMock = AutoFixture.Freeze<Mock<IMessageReceiver>>();

// act
await _azureMessageSender.ProcessMessageLaterAsync(_messageReceiverMock.Object, cancellationTokenSource.Token, givenMessage, givenDeferTime, givenDeferReason);
```

The Class

```
public async Task ProcessMessageLaterAsync(IMessageReceiver receiverClient, CancellationToken receiverCancellationToken, Message originalMessage, TimeSpan deferByTime, string deferReason) {
    ...
    await receiverClient.DeadLetterAsync(originalMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken, null);
    ...
}
```

The Exception

> System.InvalidOperationException Operation is not valid
>   due to the current state of the object.   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.ThrowIfNotReceived()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Message.SystemPropertiesCollection.get_LockToken()
>   at
>   IntegrationEngine.MessageQueue.AzureMessageSender.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Sources.....

Comment: Suggest you try going with integration testing rather than unit testing and trying to mock.

Comment: What happens if you replace `AutoFixture.Freeze<Mock<IMessageReceiver>>();` with a basic `new Mock<IMessageReceiver>();`? Is this even an AutoFixture issue?

Comment: @MarkSeemann same result. Creating a mock outside of Freeze just means that mock.Object has to be physically passed into tested class constructor

Comment: Removing *autofixture* tag, as comments indicate that this problem is reproducible without AutoFixture.